# How to use the C# g4 grammar with antlr in Python?

Tags: c#, python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to make the antlr C# g4 grammar working with antlr runtime in python3.

I automated a part of the boring stuff:

- Downloading the antlr jar in a `./tmp` folder
- Downloading the lexer and parser grammar also in a `./tmp` folder
- Generating the lexer and parser classes with a java call on the antlr jar
- Getting the related class which the thing that fails for the lexer part, I'll get back to this error below

The dirty code

```
import importlib
import inspect
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

import requests
from antlr4 import *


def download_antlr(url, destination_folder):
    _, antlr_base_file = os.path.split(url)
    antlr_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), destination_folder, antlr_base_file)
    tmp_folder = os.path.dirname(antlr_file)
    if os.path.exists(tmp_folder):
        shutil.rmtree(tmp_folder)
    os.makedirs(tmp_folder, exist_ok=True)
    response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(antlr_file, 'wb').write(response.content)
    return antlr_file, tmp_folder


antlr_url = 'https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar'
antlr_file, tmp_folder = download_antlr(antlr_url, r'./tmp')

# grammar_url = 'https://raw.github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/json/JSON.g4'
parser_grammar_url = 'https://raw.github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/csharp/CSharpParser.g4'
_, parser_grammar_base_file = os.path.split(parser_grammar_url)
parser_grammar_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r'tmp', parser_grammar_base_file)
response = requests.get(parser_grammar_url, auth=('my username', 'my password'))
open(parser_grammar_file, 'wb').write(response.content)

lexer_grammar_url = 'https://raw.github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/csharp/CSharpLexer.g4'
_, lexer_grammar_base_file = os.path.split(lexer_grammar_url)
lexer_grammar_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), r'tmp', lexer_grammar_base_file)
response = requests.get(lexer_grammar_url, auth=('my username', 'my password'))
open(lexer_grammar_file, 'wb').write(response.content)

generation_folder = os.path.join(tmp_folder, "generation")
parser_grammar_name = os.path.splitext(parser_grammar_base_file)[0]
lexer_base_file = parser_grammar_name + "Lexer" + ".py"
listener_base_file = parser_grammar_name + "Listener" + ".py"
parser_base_file = parser_grammar_name + "Parser" + ".py"


def call_antlr(jar_file, g4_file, language):
    subprocess.call([
        'java',
        '-Xmx500M',
        '-cp',
        jar_file,
        'org.antlr.v4.Tool',
        '-visitor',
        '-o',
        generation_folder,
        '-Dlanguage=' + language,
        g4_file
    ])


def get_module_class(module_name, class_name):
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    return getattr(module, class_name)


call_antlr(antlr_file, lexer_grammar_file, "Python3")
call_antlr(antlr_file, parser_grammar_file, "Python3")

# "tmp.generation"
lexer_class_name = "CSharp" + "Lexer"
parser_class_name = parser_grammar_name
listener_class_name = parser_grammar_name + "Listener"
visitor_class_name = parser_grammar_name + "Visitor"

lexer_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + lexer_class_name, lexer_class_name)
parser_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + parser_class_name, parser_class_name)
listener_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + listener_class_name, listener_class_name)
visitor_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + visitor_class_name, visitor_class_name)
```

The code works except for two things:

First, I got errors which seem to be actually warning (see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/1735)):

```
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:24:0: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:71:7: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:159:15: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:188:23: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:190:22: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:289:23: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:408:3: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:422:9: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:624:3: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:656:3: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:757:34: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:833:7: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:905:14: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:1077:9: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:1089:9: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:1119:3: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:179:8: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:185:43: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:780:38: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:819:12: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:824:11: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:71:18: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:80:48: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:135:81: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:306:8: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:330:8: symbol type conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
error(134): /home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/CSharpParser.g4:338:14: symbol dir conflicts with generated code in target language or runtime
```

Second, the python module for the lexer cannot be fetched at line `75`:

`lexer_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + lexer_class_name, lexer_class_name)`

The error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/main.py", line 75, in <module>
    lexer_class = get_module_class("tmp.generation." + lexer_class_name, lexer_class_name)
  File "/home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/main.py", line 62, in get_module_class
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/perret/Coding/Playground/Python/Playground/tmp/generation/CSharpLexer.py", line 1412
    private int interpolatedStringLevel;
              ^
```

When I checked `CSharpLexer.py` I was surprised to find that the lexer contains C# code in the middle of the Python class definition...:

```
# Rest of the code

def __init__(self, input=None, output:TextIO = sys.stdout):
    super().__init__(input, output)
    self.checkVersion("4.7.2")
    self._interp = LexerATNSimulator(self, self.atn, self.decisionsToDFA, PredictionContextCache())
    self._actions = None
    self._predicates = None

private int interpolatedStringLevel;
private Stack<Boolean> interpolatedVerbatiums = new Stack<Boolean>();
private Stack<Integer> curlyLevels = new Stack<Integer>();
private boolean verbatium;


def action(self, localctx:RuleContext, ruleIndex:int, actionIndex:int):
    if self._actions is None:
    # Rest of code
```

I am wondering whether the g4 grammar provided at:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/csharp/CSharpParser.g4
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/csharp/CSharpLexer.g4
  is correct or am I making any mistake in my antlr automation with python 3?

I made my automation code worked with the json grammar (which contains only one file) so I am wondering if there is anything wrong the C# grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the grammar files that you've linked (especially the one for the lexer), you'll find they contain embedded <s>C#</s> Java code in a couple of places. In order to use these with Python, you'd have to translate that code to Python first.

At the same time you can get rid of the warnings by renaming the conflicting names that it's complaining about.

Comment: I just realized that embedded code is actually java =/

Comment: When you say renaming conflicting names, where exactly should I edit? Also, its weird that Java code is embedded into Python code - do the Antlr people know about this bug, or is this normal? Anyway, my re-implementation of the offending bits of Java into Python is https://gist.github.com/abulka/5b6cd13fbab0a6a4497736de36427056 just in case it helps anyone - hopefully its correct esp. the references to `_input.LA(ind)`.

Comment: @abulka You should rename all the names for which you get a "symbol X conflicts with ..." warning. "Also, its weird that Java code is embedded into Python code - do the Antlr people know about this bug" ANTLR embeds any code inside the grammar into the generated parser. That's not a bug, it's what it's supposed to do. A natural consequence of this is that grammars with code in them can only work with the language that the code is written in.